# Can anyone help me with my bios?

Tags: bios, external-display, asus-laptop

so I bought my laptop a few years ago, an Asus x550ca with Windows 8 and Shortly after the screen was broken while in my backpack so it has been a stationary machine with an external monitor since. The problem is, while I was able to figure out how to go from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 16.04, I am unable to figure out how to get it to boot from a dvd this time around like it did for Linux. I have already tried the fn+f8 keys to change the display but it did nothing. Can anybody help me out? It seems like I will have to find out how to get the buttons to work or I will have to navigate my bios blind and I can't find a good reference

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop
try the function key to use  boot source menu instead of bios or try blindly using the advanced mode in bios manual and restore default

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X550CC/E_eManual_X550CC_X550VB_X550VC_VER7926.pdf?_ga=1.86584223.604664623.1473646259